# How to display Previous and Next instead of "<<" and ">>" codeigniter calendar library

Tags: codeigniter

I want to show my calendar page with previous and next month link with PREVIOUS and NEXT title instead of << and >>.

Comment: You can changes Code-igniter Calendar Library Template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the answer about this,

```
$prefs = array("template" => array(
         'heading_previous_cell' => '<th><a href="{previous_url}">Previous</a></th>',
         'heading_next_cell' => '<th><a href="{next_url}">Next</a></th>',
    )
);

$this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);

$this->calendar->generate($this->uri->segment(3), $this->uri->segment(4));
```